Flask-OIDC with Keycloak: Logout works, but auto login occurs without credentials enter
I’m working on integrating Keycloak with a Flask application using Flask-OIDC for authentication. My goal is to log users out completely (both from Flask and Keycloak), such that after logging out, the user must manually provide their credentials again when attempting to log back in. However, after logging out, the user is immediately logged back in without being prompted for credentials.
Expected Behavior:

User logs in successfully via Keycloak prompting login and password.
User logs out.
When the user tries to access a protected page /profile, user should be redirected to the Keycloak login page to enter credentials (login and password) again.

Current Behavior:

User logs in successfully.
User logs out, session is cleared, and Keycloak appears to process the logout.
When the user tries to access a protected page /profile, user is redirected to the main page.
When the user tries to access a protected page /profile again, user can access it instead of being redirected to login page to enter credentials (user is automatically logged back in without seeing the login page).

My code:
app.config.update({
    'SECRET_KEY': '20221e754l7a45909ef4Ij66ac984bea',  # random secret key
    'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': 'keycloak.json', # information about issuer, client_secret, token_uri etc
    'OIDC_SCOPES': ['openid', 'email'],
    'OIDC_REDIRECT_URI': 'http://localhost:5000/oidc/callback', # redirect link, conventionally named
    'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'client_secret_post', 
    'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH': True
})

oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Welcome to the Flask App! <a href="/login">Log in</a>'


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    print("login, oidc.user_loggedin ", oidc.user_loggedin)
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    
    # redirect the user to the Keycloak login page
    redirect_uri = url_for('oidc_callback', _external=True)
    return oidc.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri, prompt='login')

@app.route('/oidc/callback')
def oidc_callback():
    print("oidc_callback, oidc.user_loggedin ", oidc.user_loggedin)

    token = oidc.authorize_access_token() 
    if token:
        user_info = oidc.user_getinfo(['sub', 'email']) 
        session['user'] = user_info 
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))  

    return 'Login failed', 401

@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
    print("profile, oidc.user_loggedin ", oidc.user_loggedin)
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        user_email = oidc.user_getfield('email')
        return f"Hello, {user_email}!"
    
    return redirect(url_for('login'))  

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    print("logout, oidc.user_loggedin ", oidc.user_loggedin)
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        session.clear()  
        oidc.logout()
        id_token = oidc.get_id_token()
        logout_url = (oidc.client_secrets['issuer'] +
                      '/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=' +
                      id_token + '&post_logout_redirect_uri=' +
                      url_for('home', _external=True))
        return redirect(logout_url) 

    return redirect(url_for('home')) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Logs:
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  False
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:27] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 302 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  False
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:27] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:27] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:32] "GET /authorize?state=UYE5nA1KHfXwYI5Dn6Id0JJzhsZOa4&session_state=5551c9d7-4f6e-4ad8-8c9c-4e23b94fd13c&iss=http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm&code=c4976ae2-b0f8-48ae-8de0-37445b00b732.5551c9d7-4f6e-4ad8-8c9c-4e23b94fd13c.5f8c05b4-8d59-4210-a147-1a4d29ea0026 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  True
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:36] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 200 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  True
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:37] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:40] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  False
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:42] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 302 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  False
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:42] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:42] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:42] "GET /authorize?state=Hhoq1PAusTxuX7BI9zh0xRxTpukG3V&session_state=5551c9d7-4f6e-4ad8-8c9c-4e23b94fd13c&iss=http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm&code=0e10de2f-5f8b-4032-8741-639499f1cf5c.5551c9d7-4f6e-4ad8-8c9c-4e23b94fd13c.5f8c05b4-8d59-4210-a147-1a4d29ea0026 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  True
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:43] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 200 -
profile, oidc.user_loggedin  True
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2024 09:28:44] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Disclaimer: This is a basic test code, because I can't get rid of this issue. Initially the problem was that the login occurred automatically at the first time without entering credentials. Now it's the second time, but the body of the problem stays the same. So, some things like logout_url which can be seen redundant serve this purpose.
Please help :(
What I’ve tried:

Direct Access Grants in Client's settings is disabled;
Flask session is cleared and oidc.user_loggedin becomes false after logout;
Front-Channel Logout is enabled;
Tested in different browsers and incognito mode;
prompt='login';
Initially my code was with @oidc.require_login, but the same issue.

